# Text on convergence theorems in probability theory (various modes of convergence)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request

I need a text reviewing theorems and discussing with details **ALL** the types of convergence in probability theory such as almost sure convergence, convergence in probability, weak convergence, $L^p$ convergence, ... .

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a probability theory book, but Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications* covers all of these types of convergence (note that convergence in probability is a special case of convergence in measure).

Comment: Does it have central limit theorem and large law numbers and materials like this?

Comment: It does include those two theorems.

Comment: I have checked the book! For example on CLT it has discussed just 3 pages while books such as Billingsley or Durrett there is a chapter on it. Also, the Brownian motion (which is not in scope of my question) there is a chapter about 100 pages in Shreve and Karatzas whin Folland there is just few pages (-10) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Shiryaev's boook. You will find everything you need with a good level of details.

[Probability - Shiryaev](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2787445-probability-graduate-texts-in-mathematics)

Comment: I have checked the book, it seems interesting!